# When are you able to reduce equations such as $\tan(\pi/2-2x)=\tan3x$ to simply $\pi/2-2x=3x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

as the title says, I am unsure when I can do this.
Does this only apply to specific trigonometric functions?

Any help clarifying this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $tan(x)=tan(y)$ then $x=y+n\pi$ where $n$ is any integers. This is because tan is periodic function with period $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$\tan$ function is periodic with period $\pi$. So the general solution for your equation is given by $ \pi/2-2x=n\pi+3x$. Solving this will give you that 
$$ x =\frac{1}{5} \left( \frac{\pi}{2}-n \pi\right) \tag{A} $$
where $n$ is an integer. In particular when $n=0$ you will have the situation you described. But this is only one possible solution for the trigonometric function. For every integer $n$ you plug into (A) you will get different solutions for your trig equation.

Answer (score 0):

To understqnd this you should know how trigonometric functions are defined.

Here was the question asked to me ::  Why is that for any trigonometric function $f, f(2\pi + \theta )=f(\theta )$ for any value of $\theta$

I spontaneously said that it was because of their very definition.

Here is the complete description of answer i provided.

Normally we define trigonometric functions for acute angles using right angled triangle as follows.

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {opp}{hyp} \qquad  \cos \theta = \frac {adj}{hyp}  \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {opp}{adj}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {hyp}{opp} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {hyp}{adj} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {adj}{opp}$$

But we can extend our definitions for even other angles using point $P(a,b)$ on cartesian plane as follows

Definition of trigonometric functions

Consider a point in cartesian plane in $1^{st}$ quadrant as shown

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {b}{r} \qquad \cos \theta = \frac {a}{r} \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {b}{a}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {r}{b} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {r}{a} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {a}{b}$$

Now consider another point in $2^{nd}$ quadrant

[image]

$$\sin \theta = \frac {b}{r} \qquad\cos \theta = \frac {-a}{r} \qquad \tan \theta = \frac {b}{-a}$$

$$\csc \theta = \frac {r}{b} \qquad \sec \theta = \frac {r}{-a} \qquad \cot \theta = \frac {-a}{b}$$

As you can see we consider the signed values of x and y in the definition keeping in mind that r is always greater than zero.

similarly we can extend this definition (in other quadrants) for other angles.

so if we rotate the line passing through origin and $P(a,b)$ through an angle of $360^o$ we again reach the same point and hence $f(2\pi + \theta )=f(\theta )$ where f is any trigonometric function.

So as you can see by their very definition tan is repeating itself with a period of $\pi $